# javascript/jquery: detect if iframe page failed to load

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have an iframe that loads an external domain and sometimes the domain goes down or times out. I have been trying to figure out how to detect if the iframe page fails to load or not. I can't use AJAX because the domain is different from the host page (cross-origin protection).

Here is sample code of how I think it should work (but it doesn't):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe id="myIframe" src="http://www.domain.com/"></iframe>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('#myIframe').on('load',function() {
            alert('Loaded correctly');
        });
        $('#myIframe').on('error',function() {
            alert('Load failed!');
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I don't have the ability to add code on the remote domain or have a jsonp file uploaded, so AJAX/JSONP tricks are not possible (as far as I know).

Comment: Which part works? Does `load` fire if it loads? Does `error` fire if it fails?

Comment: You **can** use AJAX if you set the right `CORS` headers. You can also use `postMessage`. You can even use JSONp.

Comment: The load event is fired event if the frame failed to load.

Comment: What does the error look like, a timeout? Could you _mock_ that with `setTimeout`?

Comment: @Frits I don't have access to the other domain and so can not place code there to help or create jsonp content.

Comment: @Frist what would I parse with the setTimeout?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$($('#myIframe')[0].document).ready(function() {
   alert('loaded');    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DepKF/33/

Comment: A good try, but that will still trigger the alert when the page timesout or fails to load.